# Add external Folders to JBOSS Classpath EAP 6.3.0

Tags: java, classpath, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

I need to add an external directory to the JBoss classpath.

We used `JBOSS_CLASSPATH` variable to add files to the classpath before JBoss EAP 6.

How can we do this now? I need to give absolute path of the folder in classpath.

Comment: Please ask one concrete question per stack overflow question. Can you reformulate your question to be only one?

Comment: Changed question as per comment.

Comment: See the first result of https://www.google.com/search?q=jboss+add+folder+to+classpath